# Runtimewarning when using scipy.stats.beta.fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, statistics

If I run the following code in python

```
from scipy.stats import norm, beta
sample = beta.rvs(2,5,size=100)
beta_fit = beta.fit(sample)
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py:404: RuntimeWarning: invalid 
value encountered in sqrt
sk = 2*(b-a)*sqrt(a + b + 1) / (a + b + 2) / sqrt(a*b)
```

and depending on the size of the sample, I sometimes also get this other error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:161: RuntimeWarning: 
The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.
warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  Scipy's beta distribution has four parameters. There are two shape parameters (α and β in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)).  The other two parameters are the [location and scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family); these adjust the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the distribution.  By default, the `fit()` method considers all four parameters to be available for fitting.  Is that what you want?  Or do you want to fit just the shape parameters, and maintain the support to be [0, 1]?

Comment: I want to maintain the support to be [0,1], how do I impose that? I assumed that the beta.fit function was taking the default values of loc=0 and scale=1. Was I wrong?

Comment: By default, `fit()` includes `loc` and `scale` in the parameters to be fit.  See my answer for how to keep these fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In a comment you say that you want to keep the support fixed as [0, 1].  To do that with the `fit()` method, use the arguments `floc=0` and `fscale=1`.  Then only the shape parameters will be fit to the data.

```
from scipy.stats import beta

sample = beta.rvs(2, 5, size=100)
beta_fit = beta.fit(sample, floc=0, fscale=1)
```

This should also eliminate the warnings that you are seeing.  Those warnings occur because when all four parameters are fit, the code uses a generic numerical optimization routine to find the parameters that maximize the likelihood, and something in that code is generating those warnings.  (It might be a bug--the shape parameters are supposed to be positive, so neither of the calls to `sqrt` in the line that generates the warning should get a negative argument.)  When you fix the location and scale, the `fit()` method solves a simpler numerical problem to find the maximum likelihood parameter estimates, so it avoids the code that generates the warnings.